# Why is my array length 1 when building it with numpy.where?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to use the index values from numpy.where to print the string contents of that index. I am trying to do this by iterating over the array from 0 to the length of the array. But the length is always 1..?

```
import numpy as np
v,w,x, y, z = np.loadtxt('test.txt', dtype=str, delimiter='|',
                             skiprows=2,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), unpack=True)
a,b,c, d, e = np.loadtxt('test2.txt', dtype=str, delimiter='|',
                             skiprows=2,usecols=(0,1,2,3,4), unpack=True)

checkValue = np.in1d(a, v)
missingValue=(np.where(checkValue==False))
print len(missingValue)
for i in range (len(MissingValue)):
    print a[i]
```

This prints just one value, but the array actually has 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.where` always returns a *tuple* of arrays, even when the argument is 1-D.  It returns one array for each dimension.

For example:

```
In [2]: a = np.array([10, 5, 3, 9, 1])

In [3]: np.where(a > 5)
Out[3]: (array([0, 3]),)
```

Note that `Out[3]` shows a tuple of length 1.  The single object in the tuple is the numpy array of indices.  To get the array, just pull it out of the tuple:

```
In [4]: np.where(a > 5)[0]
Out[4]: array([0, 3])
```

For your code, change your calcuation of `missingValue` to

```
missingValue = np.where(checkValue == False)[0]
```

Comment: Great, this makes more sense now, and my code works. Thanks so much.